# Should the aerial roots be trimmed on my ficus tree?

Tags: trees, indoors, ficus

I have a couple 3 foot tall ficus trees which have some thin aerial roots descending from the branches.  I keep both indoors, and they do not get a lot of sunlight.  However, when I purchased them 2 months ago, they already had these aerial roots.

Would trimming the aerial roots have any major impact on the health of the tree?  If so, are there things I can do to offset these effects?  I have seen some trees that never seem to grow these types of roots, is this species dependent or environmentally determined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its very normal to have these aerial roots and trimming them should **not** affect the tree in any way.  There are hundreds of different types of ficus trees this could be one of the reasons why you have not seen these types of roots in the past.  It all depends on the type of ficus tree.

By the way those are some nice trees congrats!

I also found a HowTo on maintaining ficus trees: http://www.ehow.com/how_5457069_clean-ficus-tree.html

The article mentions that you can remove unwanted aerial roots or dead branches.